# Does PyArrow offer a better primitive for a "decorative" join?

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

I have a (large) number of (large) parquet datasets - for the purposes of this example, say 20 datasets about employees, each of them having an `employee_id` column together with some dataset-specific attributes, all of them hive-partitioned on the same "country" attribute; the total number of employees is in the order of 100 million (yeah, contrived example....).

For example:

- dataset 1 is `employee_id, first name, last name` - across N files, one file per country;
- dataset 2 is `employee_id, street name, ZIP code` - also across N files, one file per country;
- dataset 3 is `employee_id, years of service` - also across N files, one file per country;
- ...

In short, this `employee_id` is the equivalent of a *primary key* in SQL: each employee would appear zero or one times in each dataset - with the exception of the "main" dataset (say, dataset 1), guaranteed to contain *all* employees.

My goal is to obtain a list of employees with *all* of the attributes present in all datasets.

The basic `join` exposed by PyArrow's `DataSet` doesn't seem to cut it here: it is very slow (even when matching on `employee_id` and `country`) and it seems to materialize the entire dataset in memory. This is understandable if one considers that a relational join allows the join key to appear an arbitrary number of times in any of the joined tables, requiring that you never "let go" of a key until you're done with the whole join; but here this is not the case - if a key is found in dataset X, then that key won't be found anymore in that dataset. My intuition tells me that this property should allow for a more efficient "join" in this particular case, especially considering the hive partitioning (rows in partition COUNTRY1 need only to be matched with rows in partition COUNTRY1 and not with other partitions).

I was wondering then, is there a better way of performing this join in PyArrow?

Note that organizing each parquet file with sorted `employee_id` values *would* be an option, if there was a "join" that required it.

Comment: So you're asking for a faster way to do the join without preprocessing the data. You're shooting yourself. In my understanding, join is slow because is looking to add all the columns in a single parquet dataset. Pyarrow is faster because of the parquet <columnar> data wrangling operations (where joins are not the best ones).

Comment: You say that it *seems* to materialize everything in memory. Are you getting OOM crashes?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor, hard to say with the current dataset I'm testing with (which wouldn't really _run out of memory_), but I do see that pyarrow allocates 30GB while computing the join.